# postgres table does not exist from using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I coded a simple server that uses postgres as DB. It was working when It's not using docker but when it's dockerized and orchestrated using docker compose, I couldn't insert data in because table doesn't not exist. I did check the DB in the container and it was there.

The following are my setup and the last was the error. Hopefully to you guys can spot something that I missed. Thanks!

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  build: ./database
  ports:
    - "5432:5432" # Bind host port 5432 to PostgreSQL port 5432
web:
  build: ./app
  command: npm start
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  environment:
    DB_URL: "postgres://dockeruser:@db:5432/docker?encoding=unicode&schema=public"
  volumes:
    - ./app:/src/*
```

database init

```
CREATE USER dockeruser WITH PASSWORD 'docker';
CREATE DATABASE docker;
CREATE TABLE people ( id SERIAL, name TEXT, email TEXT );
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dockeruser
```

code

```
pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('INSERT INTO public."people" (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id', row, function(err, result) {
        //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
        done();
        if (err) return reject(err);
        // console.log(result.rows[0].id);
        resolve(result.rows[0].id);
    });
});
```

error

```
db_1    | ERROR:  relation "public.people" does not exist at character 13
db_1    | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO public."people" (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id
web_1   | error { [error: relation "public.people" does not exist]
```

Comment: Where does that database init script get called? Please include the `Dockerfile` used for the `db` service.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your database init script is getting called?  The postgresql docker uses files in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* as you can see in the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/443c7947d548b1c607e06f7a75ca475de7ff3284/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L77

You can test this by bringing up ONLY the database, by running something like

> docker-compose up db

which will ONLY bring up the db container, and then you can docker exec -it  in and psql into the postgres processes, or use your exposed port on 5432

Also, you may want to pass in the initialization of the database, username, and password the way the Dockerfile expects them, as env variables as you can see in the same file

> Environment Variables
> The PostgreSQL image uses several environment variables which are easy to miss. While none of the variables are required, they may significantly aid you in using the image.
>
> POSTGRES_PASSWORD
> This environment variable is recommended for you to use the PostgreSQL image. This environment variable sets the superuser password for PostgreSQL. The default superuser is defined by the POSTGRES_USER environment variable. In the above example, it is being set to "mysecretpassword".
>
> POSTGRES_USER
> This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of postgres will be used.
>
> POSTGRES_DB
> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will be used.

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/